# Downsampling images using LayoutParams causes unsmoothness

Tags: android, scroll, bitmapimage, layoutparams, downsampling

I am trying to make an ImageView smaller as the user scrolls, using LayoutParams. The problem is, when the imageview size is decreased, it looks awful due to the default downsampling which occurs -

### Original

[image: Resized and jaggy image]

### Resized

[image: Original Layout]

### Code

#### Downsampling

```
@Override
public void onScrollChanged(int scrollY, boolean firstScroll, boolean b1) {

    int newCoverWidth = (int) (initialCoverWidth - (float) scrollY / 1.8);
    //ImageView which is resized
    ivBookCover.getLayoutParams().width = Math.max(newCoverWidth, initialCoverWidth / 2);
    rvBookPanel.setTranslationY(Math.max(-scrollY / 4, -initialToolBarHeight / 4));

    ivBookCover.requestLayout();
}
```

#### Setting of Bitmap

```
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
    ivBookCover.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

What should i do to improve downscaling and get a smooth image

Comment: BitmapDrawable#setFilterBitmap(boolean filter) / BitmapDrawable#setDither(boolean dither) ?

Comment: @pskink Tried setting both to true.. no difference at all.

Comment: tried only setFilterBitmap?

Comment: @pskink 
I did..      

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
            Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bmp);
            d.setFilterBitmap(true);
            ivBookCover.setImageDrawable(d);

Comment: so the only way is to create a custom BitmapDrawable, override `draw()` and draw the stuff as you like